# UIAlertView Intermittently Doesn't Call Delegate Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have an `UIAlertView` that pops up and displays a progress spinner while a specific action is being performed. That action has a callback method that programmatically dismisses the progress alert and pops up a new one saying the operation completed.

The ViewController acts as the delegate for the progress spinner alert, but programmatically calling `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex` only sporadically fires. Is there something I'm missing or perhaps another way to accomplish what I'm going for (basically show spinner dialog and then alert that the operation completed)

**Code**

Progress Alert code

```
progressAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                     message:@"Progress Message"
                                     delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
progressAlert.tag = kAlertViewProgress;
[progressAlert show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(progressAlert.bounds.size.width / 2, progressAlert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[progressAlert addSubview:indicator];

[manager runOperation:parameters
         successBlock:^(id response) {
             // Callback should dismiss the progress dialog and then the delegate
             // handler should show the second UIAlertView
             // This only seems to call the delegate occasionally though
             [progressAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
         }];
```

Progress Alert dismissed

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView*)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (alertView.tag) {
        case kAlertViewProgress:
            if (buttonIndex == 0) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self showCompletedAlert:@"Completed Message"];
                });
            } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self showCompletedAlert:@"Error Message"];
                });
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

### Update

Apparently the `UIAlertView` is calling the `willDismissWithButtonIndex` method, but does not call the `didDismissWithButtonIndex`. Any clues about what is going on?

Comment: Make sure your call to `[progressAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];` is being done on the main thread and not some background thread.

Comment: Is there a way to force this call onto the main thread if it's not? The callback happens in a library that I don't want to root around too much in

Comment: Wrap the call in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`. BTW - once you do this, there is no need to do the same in your `alterView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method.

Comment: Only reason I'm doing that is because the Progress alert is launched from a custom button on the keyboard. Apparently showing a second alert causes the input to lose focus and hides the keyboard (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588714/keyboard-dismisses-after-multiple-uialertviews-are-opened)

Comment: OK but you still need to ensure that the call to dismiss the `progressAlert` is on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `<UIAlertViewDelegate>` in .h file
May be this will help you